# How to manually install a SSL .cer on an IIS 6 site without CSR?

Tags: ssl, csr

Every CSR generated by my site gave an error when submitted so I made a new site and the CSR worked fine. Now I have the certificate. However I can't find a way to install it on my original site. I have the certificate but there is no pending request for this site. How can I manually choose to install my certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just need to install the certificate to the same site where you generated the CSR/Pending Request. You can then go to the original site properties, click Server Certificate and then Assign an existing Certificate to select the cert on the other site.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best option is to export the certificate as a PFX, using the certificate wizard in IIS. This will package up the public and private keys, and let you move it to the other server. Then import from the PFX file, supply the password and your done.

Answer (score 0):

You say you "have the certificate".

How do you have it? Installed on the new site? Saved as a .cer or .pfx file?

If you have it as a file, you simply need to import it in the web site.

If you have it installed on the new site, you need to export it first.